# can I change the label of a cluster/label in a data frame by common points?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, k-means

so I'm running some processes on some data (kmeans is one of them if that helps anything)

before the process there are labels tied to certain points for instance:

df1:

```
x     y      z       labels
1.0   2.1     3.1       1
1.2   8.6     4.2       1
3.1   4.1     1.1       2
2.2   2.9     4.6       2
8.1   7.7     2.1       3
1.1   1.9     5.7       4
4.4   7.9     6.4       5
```

now that these points are assigned to these specific labels, that is perfectly fine but after I run my 2nd process (for instance another k means) the same points are assigned to different labels:

```
 x     y      z       after_labels
1.0   2.1     3.1       2
1.2   8.6     4.2       2
3.1   4.1     1.1       1
2.2   2.9     4.6       1
8.1   7.7     2.1       3
1.1   1.9     5.7       5
4.4   7.9     6.4       4
```

so then I added the labels from before and after into the same table:

```
 x     y      z       labels    after_labels
1.0   2.1     3.1       1           2
1.2   8.6     4.2       1           2
3.1   4.1     1.1       2           1
2.2   2.9     4.6       2           1
8.1   7.7     2.1       3           3
1.1   1.9     5.7       4           5
4.4   7.9     6.4       5           4
```

so as I can see, the first 2 points are titled label 1 before the process but now its titled label 2 even though its the same points.

and the same for points 3 and 4. its labeled as label(cluster) 2 but after its labeled as 1

is there any way to loop through the data frame and rename the after_labels based on the points in common based on 'labels'? I know it won't be 100% accurate because some points will be in a different label and that's ok.

so basically:

```
x     y      z       labels    after_labels
 1.0   2.1     3.1       1           1
 1.2   8.6     4.2       1           1
 3.1   4.1     1.1       2           2
 2.2   2.9     4.6       2           2
 8.1   7.7     2.1       3           3
 1.1   1.9     5.7       4           5
 4.4   7.9     6.4       5           4
```

thanks guys

Comment: How would the renaming logic know to rename 1 and 2, but not 4 and 5? Do you intend to rename only if there are multiple rows with the same `labels` value?

Comment: I see what you're saying. if that is possible, yes! I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve this! any suggestions?

Comment: so if the only way is by multiple rows that are the same, I'm willing to give it a try if you know how

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I only just thought to ask: is it possible that the two different processes generate labels with different overlaps? For example, is it possible that the two rows with `labels==1` are labeled with different `after_labels` values?

Comment: So far, I'm having trouble seeing what extra information the second process adds. In the example data you've provided, `after_labels` is just a substition-renamed version of `labels`; the resulting clusters are the same.

Comment: The values are going to be the exact same. for now, I'm running k means twice

Comment: but the thing is that, that some labels of the points changes. for instance, the first 2 points are labeled 1 but after both of those same points are labeled 2. but I know its the same cluster. I  just want the labels to reflect that the best they can. even though I know some are going to be inaccurate